# Challenges with Screen Orientation Changes in Ionic/Capacitor/Angular App Using Video.js

Tags: angular, typescript, video.js, capacitor, ionic7

I'm developing a mobile app using Ionic 7, Capacitor 5, Angular 16, and Video.js 8. My app features a video player (standard Video.js player, not custom) with functionalities related to screen orientation. However, I'm facing specific issues related to detecting orientation changes when the device is locked in a particular orientation.

**Here's What I'm Trying to Implement:**

1. **Fullscreen Toggle with Orientation Lock**: The Video.js player has a fullscreen toggle. When activated, the app should lock to landscape mode. Conversely, deactivating it should return the app to portrait mode.
2. **Issue with Capacitor's Screen Orientation Plugin**: I attempted to use Capacitor's screen orientation plugin, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. It fails to fire orientation change events when the device is locked to a specific orientation and then physically rotated.
3. **Detecting Orientation to Portrait When Locked in Landscape**: The critical challenge is detecting when the device physically changes to portrait orientation, even when it is locked to landscape. The standard methods aren't triggering the necessary events under these conditions.
4. **Maintaining Custom Video.js Controls in Fullscreen**: I need to ensure that entering fullscreen mode on the video player uses Video.js controls and not the native player controls of iOS and Android.

**Sample Code for Reference:**

```js
import videojs from 'video.js';

// Initialize video player
const player = videojs(document.querySelector('#my-video'));

// Function to toggle fullscreen and lock orientation
function toggleFullscreen() {
  // Need to figure out the code for here 
}

// Listener for fullscreen toggle
player.controlBar.fullscreenToggle.on('click', toggleFullscreen);

// Issue: Orientation change events are not firing when locked in landscape
```

**Seeking Advice On:**

- Methods or plugins compatible with Ionic, Capacitor, Angular, and Video.js for effectively detecting screen orientation changes, even when locked in one orientation.
- Ensuring the Video.js player remains with its controls in fullscreen mode, without defaulting to native controls on iOS/Android.

**Additional Query:**

In light of the challenges with `window.screen.orientation` and the Capacitor screen orientation plugin not functioning as expected (particularly not firing events when the device is locked in landscape mode and then rotated to portrait), I'm considering whether I should stop using `window.screen.orientation` altogether. I'm thinking about developing my own custom Capacitor plugin to handle screen orientation more reliably. My aim is to ensure that orientation detection works effectively even when the screen is locked in a specific mode, like landscape. If anyone here has experience in this area, your guidance on whether moving away from `window.screen.orientation` is a sensible step, and how to best approach the custom plugin development for both iOS and Android, would be extremely valuable.

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or experiences you can share to help address these specific challenges. Thank you!